# TIMx CHx in Output Compare Mode using STM32F4 series and Configuring CubeMx

Tags: timer, embedded, compare, stm32f4, stm32cubeide

I want to configure a CHx (could be CH1, CH2, CH3 or CH4) of a particular timer TIMx in the output compare mode. I want to utilize the CCRx (Capture/Compare Register of that individual channel) to generate pulses.

The main reason for using CCRx is to gain control on the Ton period of the generated pulses as my goal is to target a particular duration on the Ton period.

The only part which is confusing to me is to understand the calculations for Prescaler, ARR (32 bit) and Pulse (32 bit value).

I would kindly like to understand how these values are calculated and I know some values are supposed to e assumed. I referred a lot of materials but always end up getting stuck in the formulas as there are a wide variety of them.

I was able to generate output pulses for 10 microseconds with the following configuration:
My SYSCLK is running @100 MHz APB1/APB2 = 100 MHz Prescaler (PSC) = 9, Period (ARR) = 99, Pulse = 0

But when I verified the reason behind selecting the values using the formulas and concept available on the web, I noticed they values never tally with the results.

I tried varying the Pulse value, but it doesn't affect the pulse duration unless I change the PSC value. I want to configure multiple channels in OC mode and in that case, I want to keep the PSC value untouched and only vary the Pulse value associated with individual Channels to gain control on their respective pulse duration of the output generated pulses.

Your advices would be kindly appreciated.

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Edit 1:- I did the following calculations

To achieve a continuous pulse for a duration of 10 microsec.
I referred the following calculation.

Prescaler Output (CNTx_CLK) = (TIMx_CLK) / (PSC+1)

My SYSCLK = 100MHz
As I want to generate output pulse for 10 microsec., The timer clock frequency would be = 1/10microsec. = 100KHz or 100,000 Hz.

Based on the above formula,

100 KHz = 100 MHz/(PSC+1)
So, PSC = 999.

Now, I also came across a formula to calculate the ARR value after finding the PSC value. (ref:- Programming STM32 book)

ARR = [(fxi)/(PSC+1)] - 1, where f = SYSCLK (100 MHz), i = the desired pulse duration (10 microsec.), we have the PSC = 999
Which results in ARR = 0.

This is where I am getting stuck at the moment.

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Edit 2:- To generate an output pulse train of Ton = 1 us, I was able to correctly calculate the Period (ARR) and Prescaler value with the following formulas:-

I initially used a PSC = 9 and with the formula -> ARR = [(SYSCLK * Interval)/(PSC+1)] - 1.
I got ARR = 9, resulting in the Pulse width of 1 us (Ton = 1us).

Note:- I am still not loading any value in the Pulse field of particular channel I have configured in OC mode.

But, now, if I want to configure another channel, for instance CH2, in OC mode and generate a pulse train of duration, for instance, 1 ms, then how should I make it work? I have already configured the PSC and ARR to generate a pulse of 1 us on CH1.

Comment: Are you using the hardware output modes to generate your pulse? If so, what have you tried? Is it a continually running pulse train or single shot?

Comment: Yes, I am using the hardware output modes to generate a continuous running pulse. I tried generating the pulse train of Ton = 10 microsec. It was a trial and error by testing multiple values against the PSC, ARR and Pulse.

But my aim is to keep the PSC and ARR value fixed and achieve the control on the pulse duration by updating the Pulse value associated with every CHx.

Comment: @tinman I have add Edit 1 to the OP. Please refer the formula and calculation.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! So good that you took the [tour] to learn how this site works, thanks! This is unfortunately quite rare. -- Please do not add new information or clarification in comments. Instead, please [edit] your question. This is not a forum.

Comment: @thebusybee Thanks for the advice. I added edits in the bottom section of the main post. I haven't added any edits in a comment section as a response. Please let me know if I understood it incorrectly. Thanks!

Comment: You need to figure out what you want the frequency of the pulses to be (which will determine the PSC and ARR values), and what the duty cycle needs to be (which will determine the pulse width).

Comment: Generally you want to keep the PSC as low as you can make it, while still allowing the frequency you want. This gives you more "resolution" on the pulse width. `PSC=9` and `ARR=99` does not meet this goal. `PSC=0` and `ARR=999` would be better.

Comment: The pulse width can be between `0`and `ARR`, if that helps. With `ARR=999` you have 1000 possible widths. With `ARR=0` you have only one.

Comment: @pmacfarlane Based on your information, I was able to calculate the PSC and ARR value to generate an output pulse of a width (Ton) =  10 us.

Comment: _With ARR=0 you have only one._  No, ARR=0 is exception, the timer does not run with ARR=0.

Answer (score 1):

As @pmacfarlane already said in comments, (TIMx_ARR + 1) determines PWM *period*, TIMx_CCRx deterimines *pulse lenght* (thus together they determine duty ratio), and both are multiplied by (TIMx_PSC + 1) which thus determines granularity i.e. the timing *step* in which both *period* and *pulse length* can be adjusted. Generally, you want to keep TIMx_PSC as low as possible, but that is limited by the fact that most STM32 timers are 16-bit (exceptions are generally TIM2 and TIM5). For example, with your 100MHz timer clock, the maximum *period* in a 16-bit timer is 655.35us; if you want longer *period*, you need to increase PSC accordingly.

There is only one counting element in each timer, so *period* of all four channels of one timer is always the same, only their *pulse length* can be individually set. In other words, you cannot generate PWM with different frequencies from different channels of one timer.

Also, in 'F4 timer, you also cannot generate PWM on different channels with random phase shift, one of the pulses edges is always aligned together on all channels, as it's generated by the Update event (overflow); or in up-down mode the middle of all pulses is aligned together (newer STM32 models do have modes where this limitation can be circumvented).